# MYSQL Contraints - Multiple Checks

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, alter-table

Well i am here writing some constraints for a db I am working on and i was wondering if I could do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Course
ADD CONSTRAINT cs_level
CHECK (clevel in ('P','I','II','III'))
```

...instead of this:

```
ALTER TABLE Course
ADD CONSTRAINT cs_level
CHECK (clevel = 'P' OR clevel = 'I' OR clevel = 'II' OR clevel = 'III')
```

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL doesn't check constraints. In PostgreSQL both syntaxes are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if MySQL enforced `CHECK` constraints, I'd still be creating a `COURSE_LEVEL` table:

- `COURSE_LEVEL_CODE`, VARCHAR(3), primary key
- `COURSE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION`, VARCHAR(120)

...and create a FOREIGN KEY constraint on the `COURSE` table, `clevel` column:

```
ALTER TABLE COURSE
ADD FOREIGN KEY (clevel) REFERENCES COURSE_LEVEL(COURSE_LEVEL_CODE)
```

Comment: Yeah i thought of doing this. kinda like a lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support the CHECK-constraints. They are parsed but ignored.

[From the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You can try to put this check constraint in your business logic before inserting the row.

As [Joe Celko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko) says in his book [Joe Celko's SQL for Smarties](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hi9fMnOoRtAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:9780123693792&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false):

> Small "pseudo-SQL" products have appeared in the open source arena. Languages such as MySQL are very different in syntax and semantics from Standard SQL, often being little more than a file system interface with borrowed reserved words

A little harsh indeed, but in a way he's correct, since MySQL doesn't support a bunch of Standard SQL features.

Comment: that's kinda sad, but it is indeed true.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only supports foreign key constraints, not check constraints. Wherever you got that syntax from, it wasn't the MySQL manual.